# Subsetting dates in R

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
dat <- structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1261987200, 1261987500, 
1261987800, 1261988100, 1261988400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Rain = c(0, -999, -999, -999, -999)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first column contains the dates (year, month, day, hour). The second column is Rainfall.

The dates are not continuous. Some of the dates with missing Rainfall were already removed.

I would like to ask what is the best way of subsetting this data in terms of Year, Day, month or hour?

For example, I just want to get all data for July (month = 7). What I do is something like this:

```
dat$month<-substr(dat$Datetime,6,7)
july<-dat[which(dat$month == 7),]
```

or if its a year, say 2010:

```
dat$year<-substr(dat$Datetime,1,4)
dat<-which(dat$year == 2010),]
```

Then convert them into numeric types.

Is there an easier way to do this in R? the dates are already formatted using POSIXlt.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Lyndz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the `Datetime` to year or month (numeric), you can try `format` like below

```
df1 <- transform(
  df,
  year = as.numeric(format(Datetime,"%Y")),
  month = as.numeric(format(Datetime,"%m"))
)
```

which gives

```
             Datetime Rain year month
1 2009-12-28 09:00:00    0 2009    12
2 2009-12-28 09:05:00 -999 2009    12
3 2009-12-28 09:10:00 -999 2009    12
4 2009-12-28 09:15:00 -999 2009    12
5 2009-12-28 09:20:00 -999 2009    12
```

---

If you want to subset `df1` further by year (for example, `year == 2010`), then

```
subset(
  df1,
  year == 2010
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lubridate` package and associated `month` and `year` functions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(
  Datetime = structure(
    c(1261987200, 1261987500,
      1261987800, 1261988100, 1261988400),
    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
    tzone = ""
  ),
  Rain = c(0,-999,-999,-999,-999)
),
row.names = c(NA,
              5L),
class = "data.frame") %>%
  as_tibble()

df %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Datetime),
         year = lubridate::year(Datetime))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Datetime             Rain month  year
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2009-12-28 16:00:00     0    12  2009
2 2009-12-28 16:05:00  -999    12  2009
3 2009-12-28 16:10:00  -999    12  2009
4 2009-12-28 16:15:00  -999    12  2009
5 2009-12-28 16:20:00  -999    12  2009
```